# Windows 10 Phone rotate screen / screen orientation

Tags: rotation, screen-orientation, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile

Is there any method is called when the device screen is rotated? Whether The data is deleted and restored as in Android?

When the screen is rotated Android application is destroyed and restarted. To keep its status during the rotation, you need to call:

```
onSaveInstanceState()

onRestoreInstanceState()
```

Is Windows 10 Universal App has a store session state during device rotation?

Comment: You can use SizeChanged event. Compare Height and Width values to determine landscape and portrait mode. Maintain a variable to know the current mode. Using these you can determine screen rotation.

Comment: I just wanted to know what is happening in the Windows 10 phone / mobile when the screen is rotated the data fields are stored somewhere and re-entered or nothing happens except the change of orientation?

Comment: I think only the elements in layout renders again. Nothing happens like destroying and restarting.

Comment: I ask because I can't find anything about this in the documentation. And when I turn on the emulator screen and the physical device can't see that any method was called.

Comment: The [DisplayProperties.OrientationChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/br226152.aspx) can be fired when the device screen is rotated. Also the session will not change during device rotation.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, you've probably moved onto something else.  For anyone else that comes across this question (like I did), the answer is: Yes, there is a method. Yes, it **looks** like the data is stored and retrieved, the system handles your 'Bundle' for you.

In your App.xaml.cs file there is a method:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Invoked when application execution is being suspended.  Application state is saved
    /// without knowing whether the application will be terminated or resumed with the contents
    /// of memory still intact.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The source of the suspend request.</param>
    /// <param name="e">Details about the suspend request.</param>
    private void OnSuspending(object sender, SuspendingEventArgs e)
    {
        var deferral = e.SuspendingOperation.GetDeferral();
        //TODO: Save application state and stop any background activity
        deferral.Complete();
    }
```

This saves the state for you. This makes sense, my Windows phone will back button to the last time I hit the main screen.  If I go from app to app, the back button goes back through each one, keeping the place I left off.

When I put a TextBlock on the window and change the text with a button the text remains changed after rotation.  It actually remains changed after I 'back button' or 'home' out of the app.  Keeping state doesn't seem to be a problem, losing it may be. (I'll remember to put a 'reset' button or method from now on!)

`OnSuspending()` is defined in `sealed partial class App : Application`, sealed means you can't extend it so you can't override `OnSuspending()`, either.